# Delete file from directory inside zip

Tags: php, zip

I have a zip file called project.zip with the following structure:

```
project.zip  
  \project  
    \file.pdf
```

I need to delete file.pdf. I tried the following code but I'm getting an error.
Thanks

```
$zip = new ZipArchive(); 

    $zip_name = 'path\to\project.zip';

    $zip->open( $zip_name );

    $zip->deleteName( 'project\file.pdf' ); 

    $zip->close();
```

I Also tried with a leading backslash but with no success,

> $zip->deleteName( 'prject\file.pdf' );

Comment: Please give us the exact error message, as we can't really help you without it.

Comment: Also you wrote "prject" instead of "project".

Comment: do you have enough permissions over the zip file?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error but the result is the same, nothing get's deleted.

Comment: Yes my permissions are fine.

Comment: Can you run the php.net example on your zip file? http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.deletename.php#refsect1-ziparchive.deletename-examples Look for example.

Answer (score 2):

It's weird, but it seems you need to include the base name of the zip file in the filename like this:

```
$zip->deleteName( 'project/project/file.pdf' );
```

Try something like this to see what the filename values look like in your zip:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
    $filename = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
    echo $filename . "<br>";
}
```

Also don't forget to close the zip when you are done

```
$zip->close();
```

Comment: I get project\file1.pdf  project\file2.pdf  project\file3.pdf

Comment: So the backslash is correct for you - you must be on windows and I tried it on Linux. You might try escaping it with double backslash. Also don't forget to close the zip.

Comment: I closed it and and tried everything it's still not working. Did get the same result when tried it?

Comment: Also I forgot to mention, if I have more then one file in that directory it does get deleted, only when I'm left with one file that's when the action returns true but the file doesn't get deleted.

Comment: I tried it on PHP 5.3.10 running on Linux. I created a zip on my Mac (test.zip) with just one folder (project) and one file in the folder (123.pdf) and moved it to the server. The filename loop displays test/project/123.pdf for my configuration. It deletes fine. From your last comment it seems that you are constructing the file names correctly since it deletes the others. Starting to sound like an actual bug...

Comment: I tried it on my production server and it did work but it had a different problem, when there is only one pdf in the project folder the whole zip file get's deleted.

Comment: Ouch, that's bad. Sounds like there is quite a bit of variability in how this is implemented in PHP platforms and more than a couple of bugs. As a workaround you may have to keep a dummy file in the folder. That would work in both cases until you get a real solution.

Answer (score 1):

use forward slashes :

```
$zip->deleteName( 'project/file.pdf' );
```

Comment: maybe there is another problem. but forward slashes should be used anyway. Can you unpack the zip and post the directory structure? Then I could help you to find the bug

Comment: Inside of project.zip I have a folder called project and inside project i have a file.pdf